# No Error found but I didn't insert a value in my table

Tags: javascript, oop

The problem is upon clicking the add button, there is no value inserted in my table. When I make my program object-oriented. I can't display a values. I try to find if there is an error on my codes. But, sadly there is no error in my console log. Can somebody help me regarding to my problem or any suggestion?

```js
function Person(id, firstName, lastName) {
 var _id = id;
 var _firstName = firstName;
 var _lastName = lastName;

 this.getId = function() {
  return _id;
 };
 this.getFirstName = function() {
  return _firstName;
 };
 this.getLastName = function() {
  return _lastName;
 };
}

Person.prototype.Display = function(){
      var values = new Array(4);
      values[0] = [this.getId(), this.getFirstName()];
    
      for (var i = 0 ; i < values; i++) {
         var tr = document.createElement("tr");

         for (var j = 0; j < values[i]; j++) {
           var td = document.createElement("td");
           var txt = document.createTextNode(values[i][j]);
           td.appendChild(txt);
           tr.appendChild(td);
         }

         tbody.appendChild(tr);
         mixed.appendChild(tbody);
     }
}  

function Student(id, firstName, lastName, course) {
 Person.call(id, firstName, lastName);

 var _course = course;

 this.getCourse = function() {
  return _course;
 } 
}

Student.prototype = new Person();

Student.prototype.Display = function(){
      var values = new Array(4);
      values[0] = [this.getId(), this.getFirstName(), this.getCourse()];
    
      for (var i = 0 ; i < values; i++) {
         tr = document.createElement("tr");

         for (var j = 0; j < values[i]; j++) {
           var td = document.createElement("td");
           var txt = document.createTextNode(values[i][j]);
           td.appendChild(txt);
           tr.appendChild(td);
         }

         tbody.appendChild(tr);
         mixed.appendChild(tbody);
     }
}  

 var id = 0;
  function myFunction() {
      var txtFirstName = document.getElementById("txtFirstName");
      var txtLastName = document.getElementById("txtLastName");
      var selCourse = document.getElementById("selCourse");
      var mixed = document.getElementById("mixed");
      var tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
      id++;

      var objPerson = new Person(id, txtFirstName.value, txtLastName.value, selCourse.value);

      objPerson.Display();
  }
```

```html
 FirstName:<br>
    <input type="text" id="txtFirstName"><br><br>
  LastName:<br>
    <input type="text" id="txtLastName"><br><br>
  Course:<br>
    <select id = "selCourse">
      <option value = "BSIT">BSIT</option>
      <option value = "BSCS">BSCS</option>
      <option value = "BSA">BSA</option>
      <option value = "BSN">BSN</option>
    </select><br><br>
  <button onclick= "myFunction()">Add</button>

  <table id="mixed" border = "1px">
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>FirstName</th>
      <th>LastName</th>
      <th>Course</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's seems your logic inside the Display() is not proper. Please see below example so you will be more clear.

```js
var id = 0;
var tbody;

function Person(id, firstName, lastName, course) {
  var _id = id;
  var _firstName = firstName;
  var _lastName = lastName;
  var _course = course;

  this.getId = function() {
    return _id;
  };
  this.getFirstName = function() {
    return _firstName;
  };
  this.getLastName = function() {
    return _lastName;
  };
  this.getCourse = function() {
    return _course;
  };

}

Person.prototype.Display = function() {
  var values = [this.getId(), this.getFirstName(), this.getLastName(), this.getCourse()];
  var tr = document.createElement("tr");
  for (var j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
    var td = document.createElement("td");
    var txt = document.createTextNode(values[j]);
    td.appendChild(txt);
    tr.appendChild(td);
  }
  tbody.appendChild(tr);
  mixed.appendChild(tbody);
}

function myFunction() {
  var txtFirstName = document.getElementById("txtFirstName");
  var txtLastName = document.getElementById("txtLastName");
  var selCourse = document.getElementById("selCourse");
  var mixed = document.getElementById("mixed");
  tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
  id++;

  var objPerson = new Person(id, txtFirstName.value, txtLastName.value, selCourse.value);

  objPerson.Display();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
FirstName:<br>
<input type="text" id="txtFirstName"><br><br> LastName:
<br>
<input type="text" id="txtLastName"><br><br> Course:
<br>
<select id="selCourse">
  <option value="BSIT">BSIT</option>
  <option value="BSCS">BSCS</option>
  <option value="BSA">BSA</option>
  <option value="BSN">BSN</option>
</select><br><br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Add</button>

<table id="mixed" border="1px">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>FirstName</th>
    <th>LastName</th>
    <th>Course</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```